# List minimum with skip

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I get this error

***At least one object must implement IComparable.***

from this code

```
namespace S
{
    public sealed class C
    {
    public class Set
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public Decimal x { get; set; }
        public Decimal y { get; set; }
    }

    public static Dictionary<String, List<Set>> _SET;

    public static void MyFunction()
    {
        Int32 _h = 1, _period = 30;
        Decimal _my_decimal = (_SET[" my key "].Skip(_h * _period).Take(_period).Min().x);//Error is at this line!
    }
}
```

}

I am simply trying to get the minimum after a certain number. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To use `Min()` on a `List<Set>` you need to do one of the two things:

- the type of the elements (`Set`) must implement the `IComparable` interface or
- you need to provide a lambda that selects the value by which the elements should be compared.

So if you want the minimum `x`, you can simply do that:

```
Decimal _my_decimal = (_SET[" my key "].Skip(_h * _period).
          Take(_period).Min(s => s.x).x);
```

---

If the way you want to determine the minimum is more complex, you can implement the `IComparable` interface in your `Set` class as this:

```
public class Set : IComparable
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public Decimal x { get; set; }
    public Decimal y { get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Set other = obj as Set;
        return other == null ? 1 : x.CompareTo(other.x);
    }
}
```

The example only shows the comparison by `x` again, but you can do a more complex comparison as well.

Answer (score 1):

The big issue with this code is that you are trying to get the `Min()` value, but with a list of objects that don't implement IComparable.

In this case, you can implement IComparable interface on `Set` class or get the `Min` choosing what property should be returned:

```
namespace S
{
    public sealed class C
    {
    public class Set
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public Decimal x { get; set; }
        public Decimal y { get; set; }
    }

    public static Dictionary> _SET;

    public static void MyFunction()
    {
        Int32 _h = 1, _period = 30;
        Decimal _my_decimal = (_SET[" my key "].Skip(_h * _period).Take(_period).Min(y => y.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer did not have the bug of ... y.x).x above.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you need to implement the IComparable interface in order to get the `Min` value.

The query doesn't know otherwise what it should be using to determine what order the objects should come in.

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to implement the interface.

Your class `Set` would look something like this if you're comparing by date:

```
public class Set : IComparable
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public Decimal x { get; set; }
    public Decimal y { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj) 
    {
           if (obj == null) return 1;

           Set s = obj as Set;
           if (s != null) 
               return this.time.CompareTo(s.time);
           else
              throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Set");
    }
}
```